# Vertically aligned inline-flex inside a block problem

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Take a look at the example below:

```css
.item {
  padding: 16px;
  height: 50px;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item first">1</div>
  <div class="item second">2</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to understand why setting `align-items: center` on the second box made the first one pushed downwards.

**Disclaimer: I know how to fix this problem, I just wanted to get an explanation, like for a dummy, why does it behave like that because I struggle to understand this behaviour.**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Comment: TL;DR from both duplicate: "baseline alignment" (note that flexbox has nothing to do here, it will happen even with simple inline-block or inline-grid, etc)

Comment: @SuperDJ I think Temani is correct - flexbox has nothing to do here, but anyways thanks for trying to help! :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for those resources and sorry for this duplicate!

Comment: no need to be sorry, it's not always easy to find the non trivial duplicates.

Comment: .item {
  padding: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}  do u want this?